# Slurm - How to cancel jobs that contain a word in the job_name

Tags: slurm

How do you cancel jobs in Slurm that contain a word in job name? So for example let's say I do `squeue` in the terminal and get all my current jobs that are running.

```
JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
            468624   overcap ws_svea_   dyung6  R   12:37:16      1 brainiac
            468608   overcap fs_svea_   dyung6  R   13:47:57      1 smith
            468118   overcap fs_augcl   dyung6  R 1-15:51:38      1 gideon
            468119   overcap bc_augcl   dyung6  R 1-15:52:38      1 bb8
            468120   overcap bc_augcl   dyung6  R 1-15:52:38      1 jarvis
            468122   overcap bc_augcl   dyung6  R 1-15:52:38      1 jarvis
            467796   overcap ww_augcl   dyung6  R    2:06:08      1 asimo
            468609   overcap fs_svea_   dyung6  R   11:58:54      1 gideon
            468614   overcap ww_svea_   dyung6  R   11:58:54      1 gideon
            468615   overcap cs_svea_   dyung6  R   11:58:54      1 gideon
            469031   overcap ws_NNDrQ   dyung6  R    2:23:46      1 ig-88
            469032   overcap ws_NNDrQ   dyung6  R    2:23:45      1 ig-88
```

Then I want to cancel all jobs with `augcl` in the name. Is this possible?

Comment: Not really familiarized with `slurm`  and I was unable to get it work on my system. But given that you want to cancel the jobs with `augcl` then the jobs ids to cancel are: `468118`, `468119`, `468120`, `468122`, `467796`. Are they the jobs id you want to cancel?

Comment: If so, I might give an answer (I searched that `scancel` cancels the given job). So I can provide an answer  using some tools like `grep`, `awk`, `xargs` to be able to cancel the jobs. Do you have any problem If the solution uses those tools?

Answer (score 1):

Use `squeue` to get the list of your own jobs that are running with no headers. Now `grep` to find job names with your chosen string using `awk` to return the job IDs.

Now feed this into `scancel`.

Test with:

```shell
squeue --me --states=RUNNING --Format=jobid,name --noheader |
   grep augcl |
   awk '{print $1}'  |
   xargs echo scancel
```

Then run with:

```shell
squeue --me --states=RUNNING --Format=jobid,name --noheader |
   grep augcl |
   awk '{print $1}' |
   xargs scancel
```

If you wanted to target all jobs regardless of state you can use `--states=ALL` and likewise you can target a particular state or states by changing this as needed e.g. `--states=RUNNING,PENDING`

*Note: not fully tested by me.

Comment: Note that you can replace the `grep|awk` pipeline by a single `awk` call: `awk '$3~/augcl/{print $1}'`.