# how to cancel several jobs based on the job name

Tags: slurm

I am running several jobs on a cluster, however I want cancel multiple jobs based on its name instead of the job id. I read the slurm documentation and I see I can cancel them using scancel -n jobname
but instead of doing 1 by 1, i want to mass delete them all at once. the slurm job screen looks like this for job names

```
spc_2.30
spc_3.20 
spc_3.10 
spc_3.00 
spc_2.40
spc_3.30      
spc_3.20              
spc_3.10  
spc_2.50  
spc_3.40
```

can someone suggest a method to cancel jobs based on these names in this instance?

Comment: Would this thread be helpful to you ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714928/slurm-how-to-cancel-jobs-that-contain-a-word-in-the-job-name

Comment: Extremely! thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slurm - How to cancel jobs that contain a word in the job\_name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714928/slurm-how-to-cancel-jobs-that-contain-a-word-in-the-job-name)

Answer (score 1):

To make it reusable I would do it in 2 steps, *get the filtered list see below option 1*, then feed it to the `scancel` command, or do it quick and dirty in the other options, not fully tested, sharing my scripts

> Option 1: build a cancl script, to filter the jobs  and feed it as an `srun`

---

```
#!/bin/bash

#check processes in some mode, for e.g. standby, which matches with our process name
ps T |grep $1 |grep -v 'grep' |grep -v $0 |awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/temp.txt

i=0
if [ $(cat /tmp/temp.txt |wc -l) -eq 0 ];
then
        echo "there are no slurm jobs to kill"
else
#if there are slurm jobs, kill and count them to know how many processes have been killed
while read pid
do
        #scancel <jobid> use this to cancel each job iteratively in blocking mode
        scancel $pid
        echo "Slurm job, $pid killed \n"
        i=$((i+1))
done < /tmp/temp.txt
#show how many Slurm jobs have been killed
echo "$i Slurm jobs killed"
fi
rm /tmp/temp.txt
```

> option 2, is

---

You can just do job cancel `$ scancel jobinXX`

> option 3, is

---

I put options for nodes, status, and

```
squeue --me --nodelist=awsEC200n37a,awsEC200n37b  --states=RUNNING,PENDING --Format=jobid,name --noheader | grep augcl | awk '{print $1}'  | xargs scancel
```